# AngularJS ng-change not firing after being compiled from within a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

This is my directive:

```
directive('test', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                element.attr('ng-change', "someFunction()"); // <--- Doesnt Work
                element.attr('ng-blur', "someFunction()"); // <--- Works
                element.removeAttr('test');
                $compile(element)(scope);
            }
        };
    }])
```

Marup is this

```
<input ng-model="foo" test />
```

Now, the `blur` handler is being invoked, while the `change` handler isn't. Why?

Answer (score 2):

***EDIT:*** The question was amended and now includes `ng-model`, so I removed the original answer about `ngChange` requiring `ngModel`. Now, the double-compilation (previously mentioned as an "off-topic") is central to the understanding of the issue.

It is important to recognize that the approach you are taking results in double compilation of other directives on this element. Specifically, the following directives are of interest:

- `ngModel` - compiled/linked **twice**
- `input` - compiled/linked **twice**
- `ngChange` - compiled/linked **once**

**TL;DR**

`ngChange` doesn't fire the handler because by the time it runs, it thinks that the value hasn't change, because the value was previously changed (and now equals to that of the `<input>` element) by the first instance of `ngModel` that resulted from the first compilation.

**Longer version:**

Each compilation pass of the `ngModel` directive results in a new instance of the `ngModelController`. Each compilation pass of the `input` directive, which requires `ngModel`, gets a different instance of the `ngModelController` in its `link` function, and when the `link` function runs it sets a listener to react to changes in the `<input>` element.

`ngChange`, however, register itself ONLY once - in `ngModel.$viewChangeListeners` array of the **second** `ngModel` directive instance.

So, when the **first** `input` directive's listener notifies the **first** instance of the `ngModelController` (via `ngModel.$setViewValue), that instance doesn't have the`ngChange` listener.

But when the **first** `ngModel` directive instance sets the `$viewValue` to the value in the `<input>` element, processing all of its `$parsers`, `$validators` and `$viewChangeListerners`, the `$watch` handler of the **second** `ngModel` also sets the `$viewValue` to that of the `<input>` element.

Then, when finally the **second** `input`'s directive listener runs, it compares the `$viewValue` with the underlying `<input>` element - they are now equal - and skips the whole pipeline of `$parsers`/`$validators`/`$viewChangeListeners`.

`ng-blur` doesn't use `ngModel`, so it listens on the event directly, and thus fires (twice).

**Solution:**

So, be careful of double compilation. One way to minimize this - and definitely avoid the double compilation of `ngModel`/`input` directives - is to use `terminal: true` and a higher-than-1 priority. You can make the priority arbitrarily higher to "capture" other directives that may exist on the element:

```
app.directive("test", function($compile){
  return {
    priority: 10000,
    terminal: true,
    compile: function(tElem){

      // Remove the attribute of the directive to avoid infinite loop
      tElem.removeAttr('test'); 

      tElem.attr("ng-change", "someFunction()");

      tElemLinkFn = $compile(tElem);

      return function(scope, element){
        tElemLinkFn(scope, function(clone){
          element.replaceWith(clone);
        });
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Sorry buddy, i forgot to mention that ng-model is there (i've just edited the code). However, thanks for the hint about double compiling issue

Comment: @brazorf, well... in that case, the double-compilation becomes critical - I edited my answer